# Как правильно: "Ценность подарка не в стоимости, а в/во внимании"?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: "Ценность подарка не в стоимости, а в/во внимании"?

Answer (score 1):

*Предлог В перед словом, также начинающимся с В, за которым следует согласный, обычно имеет форму ВО*. Но это норма не строгая, вполне допустима и обычная форма предлога, особенно если речь идет о стихотворном тексте или предназначенном для торжественного произнесения с четким слогоделением.

Кроме того, колебания часто наблюдаются для слов начинающихся с ВН, ВМ, ВЛ, ВР. Так что не будет большой ошибкой написать и *"в внимании"* при абсолютно нормативном **"во внимании"**.

Comment: Вообще-то орфоэпия здесь никаких поблажек (кроме как для поэтов) не делает. Какие у вас критерии допустимости? Хотя в целом - согласен.

Comment: Критерии? Критерии я, собственно изложил. Вас интересую принципы классификации допустимый-нормативный? Я считаю, что если слух не режет и нет прямого запрета (от орфоэпии, как вы сказали), то оно и допустимо. А вы полагаете, что такой запрет есть?